# What is the objective and reasoning of no slip condition?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

My Professor used to say that there are two aspects to consider when making an assumption: The purpose of making the assumption and the justification as to why it's scientifically valid.

I would like to know these aspects with regard to the assumption of no-slip fluid-solid boundary condition.

Comment: This question enquires the purpose too unlike the said 'duplicate'.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. This is something that must be true. This isn't like a model where we assume things due to desired simplifications. What is the purpose in assuming that momentum is conserved in a collision? It isn't an assumption. It's something that must be true. No-slip boundary conditions isn't an assumption.

Comment: As the link I gave says, I suppose one could argue the purpose is to avoid infinite changes in velocity?

Comment: Makes sense that everything we write down is an assumption? Many assumptions are so deep in our paradigm ( like momentum conservation) that we forget their origin.

Comment: @patta I didn't say there is no origin. I'm saying there is a difference between an assumption and something that is true based on assumptions. For example, in mathematics we have axioms (assumptions) and theorems (things that must be true based on those assumptions).

Answer (score 1):

The link by Aaron is a justification for why it's valid.

The purpose (why we need this assumption?) is to solve the problem.  With the fluids, you have the differential equations (Navier-Stokes). But they are valid for all the problems.
For a specific applications, you must impose the boundary conditions so you can work out the specific solution.